# '500 Backend Error' on Google Fusion Table Insert Table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I would like enable a user to create a new Fusion Table through my application.

```
gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v2').then(function() {
  var request = gapi.client.fusiontables.table.insert({
    'columns'      : [{
                      'name': 'test'
                     }],
    'isExportable' : true,
    'name'         : 'Foobar',
  });
  request.then(function(resp) {
    alert(resp)
  }, function(reason) {
    console.log(reason);
    alert('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
  });
});
```

Everything appears to be working fine but my response continues to be status code 500 "Backend Error".

I went to https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/fusiontables/v2/fusiontables.table.insert and used the API explorer to execute the same. The result there was 500 as well. Does anyone know why this is happening/how I can succeed in creating a new Fusion Table for my users?

Comment: I was getting this error, but it "went away". I tried commenting out each column, then restored them one-by-one and when I'd restored them all it worked! So perhaps this sometimes isn't a problem in your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that columns need both a column name and a type to define it. That's why your request is failing:

```
gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v2').then(function() {
  var request = gapi.client.fusiontables.table.insert({
    'columns'      : [{
                         "name": "TACOS",
                         "type": "STRING"
                     }],
    'isExportable' : true,
    'name'         : 'FoodBar',
  });
  request.then(function(resp) {
    alert(resp)
  }, function(reason) {
    console.log(reason);
    alert('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
  });
});
```